# ActionCable stops working with no output - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, actioncable

I am using the following code in order to get the updates from a server:

```
const { ActionCable } = require('@sorare/actioncable');
const cable = new ActionCable({
    headers: {
        // 'Authorization': `Bearer <YourJWTorOAuthToken>`,
        // 'APIKEY': '<YourOptionalAPIKey>'
    }
});

var query = "aCardWasUpdated(rarities: [limited, rare, super_rare, unique]) " +
    "{slug, id, onSale, rarity, liveSingleSaleOffer{price, blockchainId, endDate, open}, player{displayName}}";


cable.subscribe(query, {
    connected() {
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        console.log("connected");

    },

    disconnected(error) {
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        console.log("disconnected", error);
    },

    rejected(error) {
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        console.log("rejected", error);
    },

    received(data) {
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        if (data?.result?.errors?.length > 0) {
            console.log('error', data?.result?.errors);
            return;
        }
        const aCardWasUpdated = data?.result?.data?.aCardWasUpdated;
        if (!aCardWasUpdated) {
            console.log("A card was not updated");
            return;
        }
    console.log("card");
    }
});
```

That code works fine for some minutes, but after a random amount of time, it stops printing anything.

[image]

I am running the code in a `screen` terminal using `node code.js` (an then detaching the terminal with ctrl+a+d); but I get the same output using a *"normal"* terminal.
What could be the issue? Is there a case inside the `subscribe` function that I am not considering?

Comment: maybe after a random amount of minutes your program stops receiving data, thus not activating the `received` function?